# How to backup rpm dependencies downloaded by yum while installing?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I need to install git on a machine which doesn't have internet connection. I am wondering if there is any option to ask yum to keep a backup of rpm and dependencies it downloads.

OS: CENTOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just change `keepcache=0` to `keepcache=1` in `/etc/yum.conf` file.

**NOTE:** ‍‍‍`keepcache=0` exists by default and you only need to change it to `1`; if it's not there just add `keepcache=1` to the file.